# Class variable scope problem, cross data contamination

Tags: php, class, design-patterns, scope

So I have a main class that calls another singleton class but when running multiple threads (or concurrent threads) I get cross data contamination. This is a very simple version to explain the problem. All the variable setter/getters are in the Singleton and are called and set by the main class.

```
class A {

    public function doSomething($var) {
        Singleton::instance()->setVar($var);
    }

    public function showSomething() {
        return Singleton::instance()->getVar();
    }

}
```

// Singleton

```
class Singleton {
    private static $instance = null;
    private $var;

    public static function instance() {
        if(!isset(self::$instance)) {
            $c = __CLASS__;
            self::$instance = new $c;
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }

    public function setVar($var) {
        $this->var = $var;
    }

    public function getVar() {
        return $this->var;
    }
}
```

test script 1:

```
$actions = Array(
    'one',
    'two',
    'three',
);

foreach($actions as $act) {
    $action = new A();
    $action->doSomething($act);
    echo "Action: ".$action->showSomething()."\n";
    sleep(2);
}
```

test script 1 output will have;

```
one
two
three
```

test script 2:

```
$actions = Array(
    '1',
    '2',
    '3',
);

foreach($actions as $act) {
    $action = new A();
    $action->doSomething($act);
    echo "Action: ".$action->showSomething()."\n";
    sleep(2);
}
```

test script 2 output will have;

```
1
2
3
one
two
three
```

(not in this order and it might be missing one of the values)

So why is test 1 included in test 2 results when executing both scripts at the same time?

How I'm testing:

open two terminals, execute one script in each terminal (hence the sleep) so I could see the data contamination.

Comment: you can not instantiate a new instance of singleton so all the objects are using the same instance every time. probably factory pattern will suit here

Comment: tiny nitpick, instead of `$c = __CLASS__;  self::$instance = new $c;` you can just do `self::$instance = new self;`

Comment: But doesn't each instance of the class keep a new instance of the Singleton class every time new A() is executed ?

Comment: I don't think this should happen at all, unless there is something more to it than the code shows. And just out of curiosity, are you using any kind of accelerator?

Comment: yes then have some private properties in the A() which will hold data for different number of A() objects

Comment: [Don't use singletons](http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/flaw-brittle-global-state-singletons/).

Comment: The problem is with A() object does not have any variable to hold the data it does have a new instance every time but the class which is storing the data is singleton which doesn't have an array only single variable so this gets updated on each new call to new A()->doSomething

Comment: By the way, your foreach loop overwrites $action (array value) with the new object, then tries to call doSomething() with itself as parameter...

Comment: Are you running Zend with multithreading enabled?

Comment: @dqhendricks, it's just mistake of testing, there is nothing to talk about.

Comment: @dqhendricks you need to understand the static instance of singleton which remain the same even if 100 separate instances run simultaneoulsy

Comment: I'm going to say this has no answer, and you are making a mistake somewhere. The only way for what you say to occur is if the `$actions` array has more data than it should, as the singleton has one single value.

Comment: W-e-i-r-d.  We all know those 2 scripts should have their own userspace.  If no satisfactory answer is offered here,  I suggest you file a [boo-boo report on php.net](http://bugs.php.net/report.php).

Comment: @nikic sorry I'm on the command line and php -m doesn't show the zend multithreading option. Is there a better way to check this on the command line?

Comment: @dqhendricks FYI http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_memory_allocation static memory gets allocated at the compile time not at the run time

Comment: @G molvi - The singletons when invoked from different scripts in 2 seperate threads should not be shared in this manner, it seems. Even if Zend multithreading is enabled, I would consider this a  rather serious bug if it proves to be true.

Comment: I'm with @G molvi and @OZ_ on this. Don't use Singletons here. Even if you do manage to get it working correctly using Singletons, the developer coming after you won't understand what you're trying to do, or why you're trying to do it this way.

Comment: @G molvi sure the memory gets allocated at compile time, but that does not explain this behavior. When b is compiled, it should have it's own instance of singleton in it's own memory space, least that is what I always thought. Imagine high traffic application that has singletons, they can't all overwrite each other that way ... I am hoping the OP has overlooked a detail, but I fail to see it.  Will be trying this on my own when I get home.

Comment: @Robert You are missing the point. This is not a debate on singletons, it is a clear example of data corruption when using a _very common_ coding construct. Although singletons _should_ be avoided, this behavior makes them seem as _totally unpredictable_ in most usage scenarios.

Comment: @stef: I get it. But it seems that Singletons don't actually work correctly in this scenario. If that's true, you can either try banging your head against the desk, or simply use an ordinary class.

Comment: Please add the output from both terminals including the commandline when you fire the command. Please copy-and-paste.

Comment: whats the point of having a static variable then, if every thread would be allocated a different memory for a static variable then the problem will remain the same for so many connections to single database for million users will eventually have million open connections to a single database. The static memory means that this variable will remain on its place on the server's memory for every thread to utilize it. That is why mostly commonly it is used for database connection

Comment: ugh... Ok maybe it's the Singleton, But the Docs on the Factory Design Pattern are kinda sparse on the PHP site: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.patterns.php any better references? Or Design Patterns?

Comment: Not giving up on the problem just looking for a solution ASAP so if I need to use another design pattern, so be it...

Comment: all you need to add is few properties in your A() class and in your doSomething store the value in A->property; that way you will have many A()'s with different data Using Singleton or you can make variable inside singleton to an array and on every doSomething add value into it.

Comment: @Phill Pafford: Trace it, see my answer.

Comment: `(not in this order and it might be missing one of the values)` - and you still discussing it? I'm sure outputs of two scripts was just was mixed, that's all.

Comment: @dqhendricks static remains static for every one you can simple access it without instantiating the object of that class any where out side the class if its public which means that is it not fixed with class not as per the Zend certification Guide it is not

Comment: @G molvi: You can declare static properties private IIRC, so to prevent access from outside of the (static) class.

Comment: Would having a public constructor in the Singleton cause this?

Comment: Man I could kick myself, was working fine all along except in the main class I also had a small test going on. This was causing the duplicate data which looked to be contamination the test data. Looking at the code all day I didn't see a problem. Stepping away from the code for a while, came back and it jumped out at me. uhh Homer DOH!!!! Did get some useful feedback and thanks to everyone who posted even though it did get heated a little.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You write in your question that test1 and test2 are two separate processes. From the example code you give I can not see that both scripts exchange data (not code) in a way that allows to be cross-process exchanged (e.g. via a file, session whatever).

However from the symptoms it looks like that when you execute test2, test1 is executed as well.

To better understand what's going on, you can add code into your singleton class that echo'es outwhat it currently does. E.g. setting a variable or showing it. Then you can trace why your problem occurs. You should pretty fast find out where the problem has it's root.

Alternatively if you have a IDE with debugger support at hand, you can do this by stepping through the execution as well.

```
class Singleton {
    private static $instance = null;
    private $var;

    public static function instance() {
        if(!isset(self::$instance)) {
            $c = __CLASS__;
            self::$instance = new $c;
        }
        echo 'Singleton Instantiated.',"\n";
        return self::$instance;
    }

    public function setVar($var) {
        echo 'Singleton::setVar(', $var, ').',"\n";
        $this->var = $var;
    }

    public function getVar() {
        echo 'Singleton::getVar(): "', $var, '".',"\n";
        return $this->var;
    }
}
```

Comment: No. There is no cross-data exchange in his example, and if you try it out you will see that they both behave as expected in their own memory space.

Comment: No dissent with that. I'm pretty sure the OP made a mistake somewhere, the answer is only a little help how to solve it. I think the OP has some other code running and was giving only an abstraction of his code so left out the part that actually creates the symptom he is reporting. But that's just an assumption, unless OP does not give more details and runs his script with debug output.

Answer (score 2):

I was somewhat sceptical, so I ran the code above, and ***it runs fine***.

Even with hundreds of values in each instance of script1 and script2, never once with script1 and script2 running in continuous loops did they overwrite each others singleton properties.

Tried and retried for 10 minutes, just to be totally sure.

OP is either doing his test wrong or there is a missing piece of the puzzle.

Nonetheless, ***singletons are not shared between processes***. As Expected, of course.

Comment: Seriously? I can close this post now?

Comment: Is there something in the OP's configuration that could be causing this?  An outdated PHP engine, perhaps?

Comment: Nah. I just would of liked to know how you got this result, if indeed you did.

Comment: No, I don't really want to believe you were trolling. I am curious to know how you managed to get these results.

Comment: Look it's example code and it's not a troll post as you have called it. I have designed several classes around this Design Pattern and they all run fine on their own but if I call them from a standard class something is a miss. You're right when you say it's probably my code, I thought by giving a simple example of what I'm doing

Comment: @Phill Hey. I'm sorry for the insinuation of trolling,  and have edited my post. I didn't mean to be rude,  I  actually thought it may of been a (funny?) way to get all the php dev's in a boil.